# Error when trying to load 30GB SAS file with Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, sas

I am trying to replicate what was done in this article [Loading Big SAS files](http://blog.rubypdf.com/2018/10/12/how-two-read-sas-data-with-pyspark/)

What I am doing is starting up a jupyter notebook and running the code below. I keep getting a Java load error and I can't figure out why.

```
Spark Version:2.4.6
Scala Version:2.12.2
Java Version:1.8.0_261

import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.\
config("spark.jars.packages","saurfang:spark-sas7bdat:2.0.0-s_2.11")\
.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
df=spark.read.format('com.github.saurfang.sas.spark')\
.load(r'D:\IvyDB\opprcd\opprcd2019.sas7bdat')
```

Error I always get is below

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o163.load.
: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out after 60 sec while reading file metadata, file might be corrupt. (Change timeout with 'metadataTimeout' paramater)
at com.github.saurfang.sas.spark.SasRelation.inferSchema(SasRelation.scala:189)
at com.github.saurfang.sas.spark.SasRelation.(SasRelation.scala:62)
at com.github.saurfang.sas.spark.SasRelation$.apply(SasRelation.scala:43)
at com.github.saurfang.sas.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:209)
at com.github.saurfang.sas.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:42)
at com.github.saurfang.sas.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:27)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:341)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:174)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Try to increase the memory of the executors - usually this message is related

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we were able to fix this issue by adding [Parso](https://github.com/epam/parso/) library into pyspark. [Parso](https://github.com/epam/parso/) is one of the requirements in [Spark SAS Data Source](https://github.com/saurfang/spark-sas7bdat/tree/v2.1.0).